# python 3.9 AttributeError: module 'posix' has no attribute '__all__'

Tags: python, linux, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am running flask with uwsgi, while I am running, I am getting below error

```
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 0.0.0.0:7443 fd 8
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
Python version: 3.9.1 (default, Jan 21 2021, 17:26:44)  [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/export/apps/python/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 46, in _get_exports_list
    return list(module.__all__)
AttributeError: module 'posix' has no attribute '__all__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/export/apps/python/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "/export/apps/python/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 69, in <module>
    __all__.extend(_get_exports_list(posix))
  File "/export/apps/python/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 48, in _get_exports_list
    return [n for n in dir(module) if n[0] != '_']
SystemError: <built-in function dir> returned NULL without setting an error
```

config file

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5
protocol = http
socket = 0.0.0.0:7443
die-on-term = true
enable-threads = true
vacuum = true
req-logger = file:/var/log/uwsgi/app/cart-req.log
logger = file:/var/log/uwsgi/app/cart-err.log
```

Any module is missing, same thing is working in python 3.7 but not in 3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uwsgi` does not support Python 3.9 yet.

See eg the trove classifiers in https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/setup.py

You should create an issue at their issue tracker https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues

#### Update

As "root-11" mentioned in the comment, `uwsgi` meanwhile supports Python 3.9. Also, my link from above links to "master", instead of to the current version from when this answer was created. This might be confusing.

Comment: Python3.9 is now supported: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/3c23cc311cbe9b698d05e4f436a497f615afc2bb/setup.py#L149