# AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy' has no attribute '__all__'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my GitHub CI I get errors like the one below since today:

```
File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fb4/login_bp.py", line 12, in <module>
    from fb4.sqldb import db
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fb4/sqldb.py", line 8, in <module>
    db = SQLAlchemy()
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 758, in __init__
    _include_sqlalchemy(self, query_class)
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 112, in _include_sqlalchemy
    for key in module.__all__:
AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy' has no attribute '__all__'

CRITICAL: Exiting due to uncaught exception <class 'ImportError'>
```

without being aware of any significant commit that might cause this.
My local tests and my Jenkins CI still work.

I changed the matrix to stick to python 3.8 instead of also trying 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11 also taking into account that a similar problem in [python 3.9 AttributeError: module 'posix' has no attribute '__all__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66659283/python-3-9-attributeerror-module-posix-has-no-attribute-all) was due to missing 3.9 support.

**How can the above error could be debugged and mitigated?**

My assumption is that the problem is in the setup/environment or some strange behaviour change of GitHub actions, Python, pip or the test environment or whatever.

I am a committer of the projects involved which are:

- https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyOnlineSpreadSheetEditing
  and potentially
- https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyFlaskBootstrap4

**Update:**
After following the suggestions by @snakecharmerb the logs
Now show a version conflict

```
RROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested Flask~=2.0.2
    bootstrap-flask 1.8.0 depends on Flask
    flask-dropzone 1.6.0 depends on Flask
    flask-login 0.6.2 depends on Flask>=1.0.4
    flask-httpauth 1.0.0 depends on Flask
    flask-sqlalchemy 3.0.2 depends on Flask>=2.2
```

Which is interesting since i am trying to avoid the ~ notation ... and indeed it was  a typo ... let's see whether the fix to upgrade Flask-SQLAlchemy>=3.0.2 works now.

I have accepted the answer after setting the version as suggested.
There are followup problems but the question is answered.

Comment: I have removed the use of flask altogether since problems like this showed up too often in the past and i am migrating to the reactive https://justpy.io/ for most of my projects anyway to get a better user interface.

Comment: In the meantime i am using https://nicegui.io/

Comment: [feb. 2024 update] I have faced this very issued with sqlalchemy 2.0.27! Downgrading to 2.0.16 solved my problem. It's awkward that the "trio" flask + sqlalchemy + Flask-SqlAlchemy simply doesn't work with a `pip install` command downloading the latest version of each one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems the `.__all__` attribute has been removed in the recently released SQLAlchemy 2.0.  You may need to pin the SQLAlchemy version in your config somehow. Or ensure that you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.0.2 or later, as [this issue](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/1122) suggests that version has the required fix.

Comment: thx - i am testing the assumption with https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyFlaskBootstrap4/commit/00ce9785418f9bfb83009a649dad15a77e27b80e

Comment: SQLA 2.0 has significant changes compared to the 1.x series, as you might expect.  So pinning the SQLA version might be safer than upgrading Flask-SQLA, until you can test thoroughly.  But of course that's up to you.

Comment: The changes i made in the commit had no effect on the problem.
There seemed to be no problem with SQLAlchemy 2.5.1. I don't get how the problem now appears. It seem that the use of ~ in some setup and requirments.txt files we used in the past did not have the effect we assumed and now the dependency handling starts behaving in strange and unexpected ways.

Comment: That would be Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.5.1 - Flask-SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy do not share versions.  If upgrading Flask-SQLAlchemy isn't working for you I'd suggest `sqlalchemy<2.0` instead.

Comment: The main problem seems to be pip trying to do magic things. It's making harder to find out what a correct set of versions is instead of simpler.

Comment: I have `Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1` and was surprised that this transitory dep is not locked or included.  I guess here's another problem with the overly simple `requirements.txt`.  We're solving the dependency tree as humans.

Answer (score 10):

I have solved this problem by adding a specific version of SQLAlchemy to my requirement before flask-SQLAlchemy.  Example:

```
Flask==2.1.3
SQLAlchemy==1.4 (new one)
flask-restx==0.5.1
```

I noticed that pip was installing the 2.0 version

Comment: pinning is evil and won't help it's exactly why i gave up.

Comment: Worked here by pinning, same dep tree.  Thanks  @saul-burgos.  Python needs lockfile culture.  Solve the tree once, commit it.  Idk if pinning is evil but repeatable builds is good.  :)

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked when I upgraded flask-sqlalchemy to 3.0.3 version.