# Guzzle update breaks Mediawiki 1.39.3 LTS - how can dependency hell be avoided for the future?

Tags: composer-php, mediawiki, guzzle, mwclient

Just got a:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of MWCallbackStream::write($string) must be compatible with Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface::write(string $string): int in /var/www/html/includes/http/MWCallbackStream.php on line 49
```

which manifests itself downstream as a

```
Did not get a valid JSON response from the server. Check that you used the correct hostname. If you did, the server might be wrongly configured or experiencing temporary problems.
```

in the mwclient library I am using when trying to  copy a page from one Mediawiki to another.

This happened when implementing https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/py-yprinciple-gen/issues/31

with the following code

```py
  def push(self):
        """
        push according to my command line args
        """
        if not self.args.source:
            raise "missing source wiki"
        if self.args.topics:
            topic_names=self.args.topics
        else:
            topic_names=self.context.topics.keys()
        login=self.args.login
        force=self.args.force
        ignore=True
        wikiPush=WikiPush(fromWikiId=self.args.source,toWikiId=self.smwAccess.wikiId,login=login,verbose=not self.args.quiet,debug=self.args.debug)
        if not self.args.quiet:
            print(f"pushing concept {self.args.context} from {self.args.source} to {self.wikiId} ...")
        all_failed=[]
        for topic_name in topic_names:
            failed=wikiPush.push(pageTitles=[f"Concept:{topic_name}"],force=force,ignore=ignore,withImages=True)
            all_failed.extend(failed)
            pass
        if len(all_failed)>0:
            print(f"Warning {len(all_failed)} uploads failed")
```

but can also be reproduced with a simple command line such as:

```bash
wikipush -l -s master -t crm -p "Concept:Action"
copying 1pages from master to crm
1/1 ( 100%): copying Concept:Action ...❌:Did not get a valid JSON response from the server. Check that you used the correct hostname. If you did, the ...
```

while

```bash
wikipush -l -s master -t wiki -p "Concept:Action" -f
copying 1pages from master to wiki
1/1 ( 100%): copying Concept:Action ...✅
```

happily works if not targeting a MediaWiki 1.39 LTS.

https://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Concept:Action is not special compared to other pages that can be copied/pushed with no problem.

The problem appears with certain pages and I couldn't idenfify a pattern what content might cause the problem therefore debugging was quite hard and took a while.

The JSON response is simply empty due to the fatal crash which could only be found out by setting Mediawiki to debug mode with:

```php
error_reporting( -1 );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
$wgShowExceptionDetails=true;
```

my questions are:

1. **How can an update of guzzle break my MediaWiki seemingly easily?**
2. **What's the reason for this behavior?**
3. **How can this kind of problem be avoided in the future?**

I didn't find the answers in
https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T335073 - there is only a work around but the underlying fundamental problem of why guzzle updates break a Mediawiki LTS version is not discussed.

```bash
grep guzzle composer.json 
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "7.4.5",
```

More often than not CIs keep breaking these days for reasons that are fully unclear. Both this question and [AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy' has no attribute '__all__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75275563/attributeerror-module-sqlalchemy-has-no-attribute-all)  are of this type although the enviroments are totally different. The linking element is IMHO how the dependencies have been specified. The devil might be in the details e.g. asking for 2.4 with a ^i n  composer but getting an incompatible 2.5. Why is 2.5 incompatible? Why is an LTS version assuming that later versions will be compatible and doesn't pin things in the first play. Is pinning actually a good solution here? These are not support question but very general ones which I'd like to get answers for specific to this case. How do we avoid these problems in the future?

Comment: "out of blue air" - that sounds strange. Such a message does not pop up without any changes

Comment: Also, can you share the code involved? If you are using Mediawiki without any own changes, you should report this to their bugtracker

Comment: The bug https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T335073 is already in my question and has been tracked see also https://github.com/mwclient/mwclient/issues/296

Comment: An indeed it's "blue air" since all i do is automatically installing a new environment in docker and the behavior changes without a version change of Mediawiki 1.39.3 LTS itself. So i am suprised that an LTS version is a "moving target" and the actual installation might look different any day.

Comment: Please add all clarification, including the code neccessary to reproduce the problem, to your question by editing it. Keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a support forum for software you use

Comment: Also, the given bug report includes a patch that could be applied to resolve the problem. Did you try to use it?

Comment: The patch was added after i asked the question here and only answers one of my three questions. This question is not so much about the specific problem but about why guzzle is somehow influencing mediawiki with the connections being fully obscure to me.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75275563/attributeerror-module-sqlalchemy-has-no-attribute-all for a similar problem with another library - how can these dependency hell issues be generally avoided?

Comment: It's not an update by Mediawiki or Guzzle that caused this problem, but the one listed at https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/releases/tag/1.1

Comment: That other question does not cover any PHP packages at all, so I don't see any connection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253276/discussion-between-wolfgang-fahl-and-nico-haase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll only answer on the dependency hell question. This is "Semantic Versionings' (Semver) fault" as it allows to ignore the dependencies of the dependency that is versioned.

If there are overlapping dependencies, e.g. typically in PHP that is the PHP runtime version, and code is not provided in a backwards compatible fashion, systems of multiple dependencies can easily break regardless the semantic versioning approach would have lurked a person into a different understanding.

As Nico Haase has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76072671/guzzle-update-breaks-mediawiki-1-39-3-lts-how-can-dependency-hell-be-avoided-f#comment134164890_76072671):

> It's not an update by Mediawiki or Guzzle that caused this problem, but the one listed at github.com/php-fig/http-message/releases/tag/1.1

This is in an interface package that is adding a new feature which is backwards incompatible. Normally this would require to raise a major version, however as this is only by the runtime (so a dependency it depends on it), it is technically correct to *not* raise the major version number.

However, and this is practically the typical PHP situation, your own application then - when it consumes such dependencies - **must pin the dependency versions** (e.g. lock). You can not benefit of the easy updating path semver originally announced as its main benefit. YMMV, e.g. every project is different and there may be less hard constraints with development only dependencies as they fail fast and may not break the whole project. But then each development build should capture the versions of all dependencies in use (e.g. a copy of `vendor/compsoer/installed.json` and the build environment, e.g. php version, configuration etc.).

A quick list to outline the rationale:

- Using dependencies requires (code-)review of them.
- Updating dependencies requires (code-)review of the changes.
- Same applies for the tests.
- If you don't pin the dependencies, you don't know what you've tested and what you've not tested yet.

In general to not adhere to Semver down to the PHP language level (IMHO this could work pretty well, even there are some shifts during a level) can turn out to be very unfortunate, but there is no clear consensus about this in the PSR community, nor in the PHP community overall.

And if you allow me a personal comment, I'm not even sure we've understood the problem yet.

The grandfathering contract is/was to have backwards compatibility for the runtime, which is also fail-safe.

But with more youngsters (gladly!), you get more tigers that eventually want to be the tiger team, therefore: require & pin your dependencies. This is especially becoming more and more true as the yearly release cycle of the PHP runtime starts to show more global effects. Also showing the flaw in its birth: We have yearly releases, but there is no commitment how many years at least a major version will have (I'd assume a demand of a minimum of 8 +/- 2 releases for PHP 8 and then a better distribution which versions are maintained for how long to reduce the number of releases per major in the long run).

So from a fail-safe approach with a fail-safe language, we're now going into a fail-first language that renders its fail-safe production use void without offering any comfort to deal with such inalienable PHP runtime changes.

As Semver in the PHP world is most often all and about Composer, for a PHP Composer project with dependencies from top of my head I'd suggest the following:

- Lock
- Have a process for updating dependencies (next to just running `composer update` or even running `composer install` only).
- Use a build manager
- Create artifact(s) for release/deploy from pinned versions only
- Integrate the artifact(s) (tests etc.)
- Never run Composer commands after the build stage unless you have fully understood the command and their consequences.

Comment: Lock: thats what i proposed to use for LTS versions of Mediawiki in the phabricator task https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T335073

Comment: Never run Composer commands after the build stage  - this is hard to follow in mediawiki since quite a few extensions are using composer for installation.The more important it is that the base composer.json does not introduce undefined new versions.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend a build team doing so to revisit that practice, as it poses the burden on downstream users to learn about each of those individual scripts and increases the cost of running the installation routine (best practice for CI is to disable composer scripts and interaction). Additionally - I didn't mention it in the list - pinning the composer version itself is important and projects should also publish their Composer version number they use and therefore support, like they do, for example, with the PHP or PhpUnit version.

Comment: And reading this comment https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T335073#8798850 it looks to me that pinning (via require) that version is what they are aware of and not requiring it in the past was an error as those interface packages are directly used by the project. I think this is the correct solution for this case. And you may take a high horse position insisting that such errors should not be in a LTS version, every software has bugs incl. LTS versions. And this projects looks pretty responsive and healthy to me, the fix was before the report: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T333993

Comment: I can't even think of any way where this could happen in the first place. Does Mediawiki ship any broken releases? Or did the OP run `composer update`?

Comment: @NicoHaase: They _did_ not pin the interface package. Their build however detected that flaw when the update (1.0.1 -> 1.1.0) went in. However as within the LTS version it was not yet pinned, it now did clash. So yes, technically speaking, they have shipped a broken release, however their build covered the flaw. Das kann schon mal passieren... . The moral of the story could be to list all packages in a project of type interface and then verify the projects root configuration requires exact versions. Maybe I find time later to add a poc to the answer for that. Rel. easy to miss build gap.

Comment: "they have shipped a broken release" - I doubt that. I've just downloaded the archive they've linked at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_1.39, and it does not contain v1.1.0 of that package, but v1.0.1. I don't think that running `composer update` should be run here

Comment: Take it with a grain of salt, if I've understood the scenario correctly, the issue is to depend on the interface package but not require the version in the root composer.json (as 1.0.1). I'd consider this a bug/flaw as it is an requirement of the project and that exact version is required. Just my opinion. Theirs wording: _"MediaWiki should have been pinning psr/http-message to ^1.0 as it was using it directly, and once the libraries it requires didn't disallow psr/http-message 2.*, it got upgraded to that version and MediaWiki broke."_ I have not enough insight how other components affect it.