# Flask AttributeError: module 'flask.json' has no attribute 'JSONEncoder'

Tags: python, flask

My flask app was working prior to upgrades. I was having trouble with sending email when there was a forgot-reset-password. To try and fix this I recently upgraded some modules for my flask app. The modules that I upgraded with current versions are:

- email-validator==2.0.0.post2
- Flask==2.3.1
- itsdangerous==2.1.2

The Traceback error that I am  getting now is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\my_folder\sales\app.py", line 1, in <module>
from product import app
File "C:\Users\my_folder\sales\product\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
from product.agents.views import agents_bp
File "C:\Users\my_folder\sales\product\agents\views.py", line 7, in <module>
from product.agents.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm, UpdateAccountForm, ResetPasswordForm, RequestResetForm
File "C:\Users\my_folder\sales\product\agents\forms.py", line 1, in <module>
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
File "C:\Users\my_folder\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from .recaptcha import Recaptcha
File "C:\Users\my_folder\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\recaptcha\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .fields import RecaptchaField
File "C:\Users\my_folder\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\recaptcha\fields.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import widgets
File "C:\Users\my_folder\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\recaptcha\widgets.py", line 6, in <module>
JSONEncoder = json.JSONEncoder
AttributeError: module 'flask.json' has no attribute 'JSONEncoder'
```

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: You probably have a module named `json.py`. Avoid naming your files the same as libraries from the standard library or other packages

Comment: @mousetail  The only json.py files that I am seeing is in the in environment. Should I rename this one?
flask_env\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\rich\json.py or 
flask_env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\json.py

Comment: Those should not be in your python path so shouldn't be importable directly

Comment: @mousetail I just realized that I missed the last line of the traceback.

Comment: I try to avoid flask since it's notorious for this kind of problem see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75275563/attributeerror-module-sqlalchemy-has-no-attribute-all

Comment: @WolfgangFahl, What do you use instead of Flask?

Comment: @ShaneS - FastAPI, justpy, nicegui ...

Comment: @mousetail Why? That's why there's namespace hierarchies. Naming your file json.py isn't an issue unless you do wrong things with sys.path / PYTHONPATH

Comment: @BlakBat Yes it is, a local file named `json.py` will override the build in module by default

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python has had a builtin JSONEncoder since at least 3.2, making Flask's version redundant.  So it's reasonable to remove it.

If this was a module you controlled, you could just replace your line `JSONEncoder = json.JSONEncoder` with

```
from json import JSONEncoder
```

Since you don't control this library though, you should notice which library that is trying to include it, in your case that's `flask_wtf`. When you [check PyPi for that library](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-WTF/#history) you'll see that there's a few recent releases, suggesting the first thing you should try is updating that version on Flask-WTF.

Answer (score 13):

The solution I found is to uninstall Flask and install an older version.

```
pip uninstall Flask
```

```
pip install Flask==2.2.3
```

The problem with this solution is a still get an error on the POST for forgot-reset-password.
Hopefully someone finds a new better solution later on.

**Update**

I would like to recommend Kacey Saff's solution found on this page https://stackoverflow.com/a/76325779/5091720
This is the solution that I ended up moving to.

Comment: It works with Flask==2.2.5

Answer (score 6):

These attributes has been removed from flask version 2.3.0
see this release notes: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/changes/#version-2-3-0

Comment: thanks for the info, any idea how to fix the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'll quote part of it: "*json_encoder and json_decoder attributes on app and blueprint, and the corresponding json.JSONEncoder and JSONDecoder classes, are removed.*". So it appears that json.JSONEncoder is still being referenced in the flask module code even though it is removed.

Answer (score 5):

A specific line from the error message held the clue:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
```

Upgrading the Flask-WTF package to the latest version fixed the issue for me:

```
Flask-WTF~=1.1.1
```

Comment: Tried with Flask-WTF 1.1.1 , but it didn't work for me. Flask 2.3.2, itsdangerous 2.1.2, flask_mongoengine 1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue today. For me, updating my version of connexion solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. This does not appear to be the solution for me because I don't even have this python package.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the previous answers and make it sure that you get no such errors in the future:

Generally if you have something like that:

```
from . import widgets 
File "C:\Users\my_folder\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\recaptcha\widgets.py", line 6, in <module>
JSONEncoder = json.JSONEncoder
AttributeError: module 'flask.json' has no attribute 'JSONEncoder'
```

You can see in the filepath that there is the site-package flask_wtf which throws this error.

If you are lucky, the maintainer of flask-wtf is going to maintain the package and getting you an update. This leads me to the first thing you can do:

1. Check if you have the latest package of flask-wtf installed. This is usually done with a `pip install --upgrade flask-wtf`

If that didn't help, then this means that either 1) the package is not maintained anymore or 2) the package has a bit of a delay being maintained. So you have your second option:

2. you have to go to the latest compatible flask. But which one is that? You can always look at the changelog. But maintainers usually
   don't depreciate functions without warning beforehand. Usually also
   it is agreed that versions such as flask follow
   [sematicversioning](https://semver.org/) with MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH. Normally, minors
   should be backwards compatible but in flask this is not always the
   case. that means that the version causing the problem has been 2.3.1
   you should test with the latest version which is below 2.3 which has
   been 2.2.5.

**You can do things to prevent such issues in the future.** Notably:

1. Use something like **pip-tools** which helps you to avoid installing incompatible packages and have a good overview over dependencies
2. Look at warnings in your code **before updating**. For the JSONEncoder issue in question, there has been for a while the following warning message `DeprecationWarning: 'app.json_encoder' is deprecated  and will be removed in Flask 2.3. Customize 'app.json_provider_class' or 'app.json' instead.`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error after **upgrading my Flask version**, I used the **built-in JSON encoder** instead.

Simply, I changed

```
from flask.json import JSONEncoder
```

to

```
from json import JSONEncoder
```

and the problem was fixed without any casualties.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from json import JSONEncoder
import decimal
from datetime import datetime, date

# Keep a datetime.date in ‘yyyy-mm-dd’ format when using Flask’s jsonify
class CustomJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        '''Keep a datetime.date in ‘yyyy-mm-dd’ format when using Flask’s jsonify'''
        try:
            if isinstance(obj, date):
                return obj.isoformat()
            elif isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
                return float(obj)
            iterable = iter(obj)
        except TypeError:
            pass
        else:
            return list(iterable)
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

application = Flask(__name__)
application.json_encoder = CustomJSONEncoder
```