# ImportError: cannot import name 'JSONEncoder' from 'flask.json'

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, python-venv

I'm following a course on full-stack with Flask. My **init**.py looks like:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

db = MongoEngine()
db.init_app(app)

from application import routes
```

However, when importing `from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine`, I'm getting an ImportError:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'JSONEncoder' from 'flask.json'
```

My venv looks like:

```
blinker==1.6.2
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
dnspython==2.3.0
email-validator==2.0.0.post2
Flask==2.3.2
flask-mongoengine==1.0.0
Flask-WTF==1.1.1
idna==3.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
mongoengine==0.27.0
pymongo==4.4.0
python-dotenv==1.0.0
Werkzeug==2.3.6
WTForms==3.0.1
```

Is there anything I can do here to avoid this conflict? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76107450/flask-attributeerror-module-flask-json-has-no-attribute-jsonencoder

Comment: thanks for the info, not quite. I saw the post but it didn't make clear to me that I have to downgrade Flask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

flask_mongoengine seems to be not currently maintained and does not work with current Flask versions. If you absolutely must use it, you need to downgrade your Flask version, which may (and likely will) get you into other trouble.

There is an issue on github regarding your error message:
https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/issues/522

The deprecation warning came with Flask 2.2.0 in 08/2022:
[Flask Changes](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/changes/#version-2-2-0)

After a brief look at the repo, it seems the maintainer was already on it: https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/blob/master/flask_mongoengine/json.py

Comment: ooh, that's why. I saw a post on the mongodb help page (https://docs.mongoengine.org/projects/flask-mongoengine/en/latest/flask_config.html) saying they don't have enough developers. Thanks a lot for the info.

Answer (score 5):

It appears the repo is not maintained recently. Instead of degrading flask, you should install flask-mongoengine from this fork https://github.com/idoshr/flask-mongoengine/tree/1.0.1

uninstall current version by

```
 pip uninstall flask-mongoengine
```

And install using

```
pip install git+https://github.com/idoshr/flask-mongoengine.git@1.0.1
```

This worked for me. I got this from here https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/issues/525#issuecomment-1717066429

Answer (score 2):

I downgrade my flask version and issue solved.

> pip install flask==2.2.5