# Python 3.7: AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy' has no attribute '__all__'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, attributeerror

I'm having trouble with running a test file that written by someone else. Below are some details. Does anyone know what might solve this error?

Python Version: 3.7

```
    Local Requirements:
    aniso8601==9.0.1
    appnope==0.1.3
    attrs==23.1.0
    backcall==0.2.0
    blinker==1.6.3
    cffi==1.15.1
    click==8.1.7
    decorator==5.1.1
    Flask==2.2.0
    Flask-DebugToolbar==0.14.1
    flask-restx==0.5.1
    Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.0.5
    Flask-WTF==1.1.1
    greenlet==3.0.3
    importlib-metadata==6.7.0
    importlib-resources==5.12.0
    ipython==7.34.0
    ipython-genutils==0.2.0
    itsdangerous==2.1.2
    jedi==0.19.1
    Jinja2==3.1.2
    jsonschema==4.17.3
    MarkupSafe==2.1.3
    matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
    packaging==23.2
    parso==0.8.3
    pexpect==4.9.0
    pickleshare==0.7.5
    pkgutil_resolve_name==1.3.10
    prompt-toolkit==3.0.43
    psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
    ptyprocess==0.7.0
    pycparser==2.21
    Pygments==2.17.2
    pyrsistent==0.19.3
    pytz==2023.3.post1
    simplegeneric==0.8.1
    six==1.16.0
    SQLAlchemy==2.0.23
    traitlets==5.9.0
    typing_extensions==4.7.1
    wcwidth==0.2.12
    Werkzeug==2.2.3
    WTForms==3.0.1
    zipp==3.15.0
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Failed to import test module: test_forms
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/jkelly/Python/Flask/database-dj/database-dj/playlist-app/tests/test_forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/jkelly/Python/Flask/database-dj/database-dj/playlist-app/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from models import db, connect_db, Playlist, Song, PlaylistSong
  File "/home/jkelly/Python/Flask/database-dj/database-dj/playlist-app/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    db = SQLAlchemy()
  File "/home/jkelly/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 680, in __init__
    _include_sqlalchemy(self, query_class)
  File "/home/jkelly/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 79, in _include_sqlalchemy
    for key in module.__all__:
AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy' has no attribute '__all__'
```

I've tried using Python 3.10, but it won't recognize the app module. The original files were made using Python 3.7 and I was directed by team to use 3.7 so I have.

I'm hoping there is a different set of requirements that will fix this.

Comment: I noticed that your issue is quite specific and involves an error with SQLAlchemy in a Python environment. It's possible that this problem has been encountered and resolved by others. I recommend checking out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75275563/attributeerror-module-sqlalchemy-has-no-attribute-all

Comment: Note that the final line in the traceback does not exist in the [source code for Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.05](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/3.0.5/src/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py). Check your version with `pip  list` or `pip show Flask-SQLAlchemy`  and perhaps re-install.